# Deleting files by date in a shell script?

Tags: bash

I have a directory with lots of files. I want to keep only the 6 newest. I guess I can look at their creation date and run rm on all those that are too old, but is the a better way for doing this? Maybe some linux command I could use?

Thanks!

:)

Comment: How does `find /my/path -type f -mtime +6 -exec rm {} \;` look?

Comment: Bad. If the last 6 files are ober 6 days old, they'll all be deleted. If the last 6 days created a billion files, none will be deleted. Also,`-delete` is simpler than `-exec rm P{ ]\;`

Comment: @user1856596 that will get the files modified in the last 6 days, what you want (according to your question) is those modified after the most recent 6 **files**

Comment: I should have added that those files are created in a cron job, one each day. They wont be modified, just created by mysqldump and thats it.

Comment: In that case, the find command seems ok. Oh, the art of specifying requirements :)

Answer (score 5):

```
rm -v $(ls -t mysvc-*.log | tail -n +7)
```

- `ls -t`, list sorted by time
- `tail -n +7`, *+7* here means *length-7*, so all but first 7 lines
- `$()` makes a list of strings from the enclosed command output
- `rm` to remove the files, of course
- Beware files with space in their names, `$()` splits on any white-space!

Comment: Would you explain that command please? I am not a Linux pro :). Thanks

Comment: Thanks @JanHudec :) @user1856596 Beware of filenames with whitespace characters (or other funnies) here, though: the `find` command would be a lot _safer_ in practice

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on it, as a script. It does handle spaces in file names even if it is a bit of a hack.

```
#!/bin/bash

eval set -- $(ls -t1  | sed -e 's/.*/"&"/')

if [[ $# -gt 6 ]] ; then
    shift 6
    while [[ $# -gt 0 ]] ; do
        echo "remove this file: $1" # rm "$1"
        shift
    done
fi
```

The second option to ls up there is a "one" for one file name per line. Doesn't actually seem to matter, though, since that appears to be the default when ls isn't feeding a tty.